# Angular Material 2.0.0-beta.3 Depends on OpaqueTokens but they are Deprecated in Angular 5

Tags: angular, angular-material2, angular5

Our application was updated from Angular v4 to v5 with minimal difficulties, but after trying to migrate from Angular Material v2.0.0-beta.3 to v5.0.1 there were a bunch of UI issues we don't have time to address, but Angular Material v2.0.0-beta.3 depends on `OpaqueTokens`.

Is it possible to pull in `OpaqueTokens` or implement/fake them to allow us time to work on Angular Material update issues when there is more time?

Comment: Material 5 comes along with Angular 5, you'll have to stick to an older version of Angular if you don't want to upgrade Material. It's not too painful of a change for most items, and it's always recommended to keep on the latest stable.

Comment: k, yah Angular Material changes from v2.x to 5.x cause a bunch of UI issues for us that will require some fixes.  So we'll have use the old versions of both do our updates and migrate next year sometime.

Comment: This depends on how the app is being built. Generally there's no simple way. Fork Material and make it use InjectionTokens.